# previous item in ipython console emacs shifts text to the left before console prompt

Tags: emacs, ipython, python-mode

I am using python-mode 6.0.10 with the ipython console. When I try to bring up a previous history item it is shifted to the left preceeding the console input prompt e.g.

In [51]: (hit M-p to get previous item)
plt.plot(u_class)In[51]: (hitting M-p after this yields a "not a command line" error).

What I have to do now is to effectively kill the badly formatted previous item text and yank it in front of the "In[51]:" . After that repeated use of M-p works as desired.

Is there a way to fix this? This behaviour happens both on OS X and windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the latest build of ipython (2927) in conjuction with python-mode 6.0.1. solves this issue.